# Find string between strings and extract

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I need to find a way to get the the String after "Operand stack:"   and between "Execution stack:". (e.g: " --nostringval--   _Swis721BT-Bold   Swis721BT-Bold   0   0   Courier")

I'm trying with RegEx but I cant't figure out how :(

`Error: /invalidfont in /findfont
    Operand stack:
       TCCING+Helvetica-Condensed-Bold   Helvetica-Condensed-Bold
    Execution stack:
       %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1932   1   3   %oparray_pop   1931   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1915   1   3   %oparray_pop   1803   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1884   2   10   %oparray_pop
    Dictionary stack:
       --dict:1178/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:94/200(L)--   --dict:54/73(L)--   --dict:209/209(L)--   --dict:72/140(L)--   --dict:0/10(G)--   --dict:0/10(L)--   --dict:0/50(ro)(G)--   --dict:56/71(L)--
    Current allocation mode is local
    Last OS error: No such file or directory
    Current file position is 223399
    Error: /invalidfont in /findfont
    Operand stack:
       --nostringval--   _Swis721BT-Bold   Swis721BT-Bold   0   0   Courier
    Execution stack:
       %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1932   1   3   %oparray_pop   1931   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1915   1   3   %oparray_pop   1803   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1884   6   9   %oparray_pop
    Dictionary stack:
       --dict:1178/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:96/200(L)--   --dict:7/25(L)--   --dict:11/14(ro)(L)--   --dict:64/68(ro)(L)--   --dict:21/24(L)--   --dict:87/95(L)--   --dict:98/107(L)--
    Current allocation mode is local
    Last OS error: No such file or directory
    Current file position is 42585
    Error: /invalidfont in /findfont
    Operand stack:
       --nostringval--   _Helvetica   Helvetica   0   0   Courier
    Execution stack:
       %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1932   1   3   %oparray_pop   1931   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1915   1   3   %oparray_pop   1803   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1884   6   9   %oparray_pop
    Dictionary stack:
       --dict:1178/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:96/200(L)--   --dict:7/25(L)--   --dict:11/14(ro)(L)--   --dict:64/68(ro)(L)--   --dict:21/24(L)--   --dict:87/95(L)--   --dict:98/107(L)--
    Current allocation mode is local`

Comment: What is the best regex that you tried?

Comment: I tried this

`Operand stack:((?:.|[\n\r])+)Execution stack:`
But the result is the whole text basically

Comment: your regex works if you put a question mark behind the + to make your search lazy.

Comment: @MalawiM Yup, that regex was pretty close :) You could also try [this one](http://regex101.com/r/zA4oP3) which wouldn't need the `(?s)` modifier provided there's only one line to match and prevents unnecessary space around the extracted text,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Operand stack:(.*?)Execution stack:
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/xL1vU2).

Notes:

- Make sure to use the `s` modifier so that dot matches new lines.
- Be sure to put a question mark behind the `.*` so as to make the search [lazy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html).

Comment: Thank you! Since I was using Sublime Text I needed to look up the Boost Regex Syntax. I used this:

`(?s)Operand stack:(.*?)Execution stack:`